# How fix keyboard input lag?

Tags: java, multithreading, keyboard, lag

I've written a program to accept user answers to some questions, like "A", "B" or "C". If user answers them late, the program make different questions, like "D", "E" of "F". When user answer to these "D", "E", or "F", the program should restart to answer with "A", "B" or "C". However, sometimes this does not work, the program still continue asking with "D", "E" of "F". Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Latency latency = new Latency();
        latency.start();
    }

    private static String choosePhrase(int seconds, int average) {
        if (seconds > average + 10) {
            return "¿D?";
        } else if (seconds > average + 5) {
            return "¿E?";
        } else {
            return "¿F?";
        }
    }
}

class Latency {

    int seconds = 0, average = 5;
    MyThread myThread;
    MyThread_r myThread_r;
//    public volatile boolean answered = true;
    ObjectToPass o = new ObjectToPass();

    public void start() {
        String s = "";
        while (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {

            seconds = 0;
            if (myThread_r != null) {
                myThread_r.shutdown();
            }

            if (o.answered) {
                o.answered = false;
                myThread = null;
                myThread = new MyThread(o);
                Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
                t.start();
            } else {
                if (myThread != null) {
                    myThread.shutdown();
                }

                myThread_r = null;
                myThread_r = new MyThread_r(o);
                Thread t = new Thread(myThread_r);
                t.start();
            }

            long createdMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while (!this.o.getPlay() && seconds < average) {
                long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                seconds = (int) ((nowMillis - createdMillis) / 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ObjectToPass {

    boolean answered = true;

    public synchronized boolean getPlay() {
        return answered;
    }

    public synchronized void setPlay(boolean answered) {
        this.answered = answered;
    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

    ObjectToPass o;
    static String[] questions = {"¿A?", "¿B?", "¿C?"};
//    public volatile boolean answered = true;

    public MyThread(ObjectToPass o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread running");
        Double d = Math.random() * 100;
        int n = (int) (Math.ceil(d) % 3);
        String question = questions[n];

        System.out.println(question);

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = keyboard.nextLine();
        this.o.setPlay(true);
//        stop();
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return;
    }
}

class MyThread_r implements Runnable {

    ObjectToPass o;
    static String[] questions = {"¿D?", "¿E?", "¿F?"};
//    public volatile boolean answered = true;

    public MyThread_r(ObjectToPass o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread running");
        Double d = Math.random() * 100;
        int n = (int) (Math.ceil(d) % 3);
        String question = questions[n];

        System.out.println(question);

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = keyboard.nextLine();
        this.o.setPlay(true);
//        stop();
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: When reading input from t he console, you are in a mess because of the console. If you want to do this in a reliable way, you're better off making a swing or JavaFX gui. Then you can read from then keyboard in a precise manner. But if this is school work and your not allowed to, this is harder.

Comment: Thank you, I've solved the issue according your suggestion, as I show below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I've solved it according your suggestion. I've replaced

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = keyboard.nextLine();
```

with

```
Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
int oo = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "¿Question?", "Questions",
                JOptionPane.YES_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                null, options, options[0]);
```